# Задача "Электронные часы"

Tags: pascal

***Электронные часы 2:***

Электронные часы показывают время в формате `h:mm:ss`, то есть сначала записывается количество часов, потом обязательно двузначное количество минут, затем обязательно двузначное количество секунд. Количество минут и секунд при необходимости дополняются до двузначного числа нулями.

С начала суток прошло `n` секунд. Выведите, что покажут часы.
**Пример: ввод - 3602, вывод - 1:00:02** Решить нужно как то с помощью div, mod... которые я как раз не очень понимаю, ***решение может быть написано на C++ или C#.***

//Первую задачу этого типа я уже решил: ***Электронные часы 1:***

Дано число `n`. С начала суток прошло `n` минут. Определите, сколько часов и минут будут показывать электронные часы в этот момент. Программа должна вывести два числа: количество часов (от 0 до 23) и количество минут (от 0 до 59). Учтите, что число n может быть больше, чем количество минут в сутках.

```
 var
     a, b, n:longint;
    begin
     readln(n);
     a:=(n div 60)mod 24;
     b:=n mod 60;
     writeln(a,' ',b);
     end.
```

Вот так решается первая версия, а как вторая?

Answer (score 2):

Блин, это же арифметика! 3 класс!!! Вспоминайте целочисленное деление:

```
7 : 2 = 3 (остаток: 1)
7 div 2 = 3 (результат)
7 mod 2 = 1 (остаток)
125 div 60 = 2
125 mod 60 = 5
125 секунд = 2*60 секунд + 5 секунд = 2 минуты 5 секунд

1 час = 60 минут = 60*60 секунд = 3600 секунд

3752 div 3600 = 1
3752 mod 3600 = 152
3752 секунды = 1 час + 152 секунды

152 div 60 = 2
152 mod 60 = 32
152 секунды = 2 минуты + 32 секунды

3752 секунды = 1 час + 152 секунды = 1 час + 2 минуты + 32 секунды
```

Разберитесь с этим, потом за ведущие нули возьметесь.

Comment: спасибо, а как нули добавлять при необходимости?
а то получилось как то так:

program e2;

var
  n, h, mm, ss: longint;

begin
  readln(n);
  h := n; mm := n; ss := n;
  h := n div 3600;
  mm := (n mod 3600) div 60;
  ss := n mod 60;
  writeln('',h, ':',mm,':',ss);
end.

Comment: Один из способов: проверять число на то, что оно меньше 10. А также, либо переводить числа в строки, либо манипулировать выводом. Еще можно посмотреть функцию Format()<br>
var <br>
....
h_str, mm_str, ss_str, out_str: string;
begin <br>
....
str(h, h_str); <br>
str(mm, mm_str); <br>
str(ss, ss_str); <br>
out_str := h_str; <br>
if mm < 10 then <br>
  out_str := out_str + ':0' + mm_str <br>
else <br>
  out_str := out_str + ':' + mm_str; <br>
if ss < 10 then <br>
  out_str := out_str + ':0' + ss_str <br>
else <br>
  out_str := out_str + ':' + ss_str; <br>
writeln(out_str); <br>
end.

Answer (score 2):

```
var
  n: integer;
  h, m, s: integer;

begin
  readln(n);
  h := (n mod (3600*24)) div 3600;
  m := (n mod 3600) div 60;
  s := (n mod 60);
  write(h, ':', m div 10, m mod 10, ':', s div 10, s mod 10);

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var
     a, b,c, n:longint;
    begin
     readln(n);
     a:=((n div 60) div 60 )mod 24;
     b:=(n div 60)mod 60;
     c:=n mod 60;
     writeln(a,' ',b,' ',c);
     end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a,b,c,n: longint;
begin
Read (n);
a:=n div 3600 mod 24;
b:=n div 60 mod 60;
c:= n mod 60;
if (b<9) and (c<9) then
write (a,':0',b,':0',c);
if (b>9) and (c<9) then
write (a,':',b,':0',c);
if (b>9) and (c>9) then
write (a,':',b,':',c);
if (b<9) and (c>9) then
write (a,':0',b,':',c);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
S = int(input())
h = S // 3600
m = S // 60 % 60
s = S % 60
print(str(h) + ":", str(m) + ":", s)
```

PYTHON

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

n=int(input())

h=((n//60)//60)%24

m=n//60%60

m1=str(m//10)

m2=str(m%10)

m=m1+m2

s=n%60

s1=str(s//10)

s2=str(s%10)

s=s1+s2

print(h,m,s,sep=':')